# How to update inventory by sku and other custom fields with magento API?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to update inventory by SKU and other custom fields with magento API ?

I am using cataloginventory_stock_item method of magento API for update inventory which gives only facility for update inventory by SKU where i have two another custom field in magento which define as ISBN and Store ID. So i want to update inventory stock level by ISBN and Store ID. I am using magento API and SOAP V1 method.

Comment: please read FAQ for asking question. This not a correct way to ask a question. Add your code, algorithm you have tried and mention what are the problem you are facing in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SOAP API of Magento to do that. Below is the link that shows how to connect to Magento and update a product:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.update.html

abnab

> Hi Neel,
>
> It does makes sense what you want to do.  If I were you I would do this
>
> Just  find you attribute_id from  catalog_product_entity_varchar   (easy way to search you  custom value in this table
>
> e.g : if one of ur ISBN is S123 I would do   Select attribute_id from catalog_product_entity_varchar where value='S123'; which gives
>   you your customer attribute_id)
>
> then join that table with catalog_product_entity where you can find the product SKU  (add where condition for attribute_id)
>
> then you can use catalog_product.update  to update your product
>
> Hope this helps
>
> Abnab

Comment: Thanks abnab, but i want to update inventory by custom field like ISBN and Store ID which i created where catalog_product.update (SOAP V1) method provides only SKU or Product ID parameter for update products.

Comment: added a new solution above. HOpe that helps

Comment: hi abnab, thanks for your interest. i want something like this using magento API. 

UPDATE table_name 
SET qty = new_qty
WHERE ISBN(new attribute) = 1234;

Comment: you wont have the quantity and ISBN  attribute in the same table

Comment: I have no conceren with table....
I just want to update inventory by my new attribute ISBN(unique) instead of SKU/Product ID using cataloginventory_stock_item.update (SOAP V1) method.

Comment: I guess its is not possible to do it directly. SOAP API only takes SKU or Product ID to update product.  My Idea was to get product ID or SKu though ISB then update the quantity

Comment: Actually abnab my problem is big which i describe here below...

Is it possible to assign different qty to one product for different store. For eg.

I have two store A and B which have same one common product T-SHIRT. i want to keep different qty for T-SHIRT in both store A and B. Like A have qty-5 for T-SHIRT while store B have qty-10 for T-SHIRT.

Hope you understand now.

Comment: Doesn't the storeView  argument sort it out ?

Comment: Could you please know me best way to do this ?

Comment: Not getting you for this line "Doesn't the storeView argument sort it out ? –".